# Select displaying incorrect results for matches and teams

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few questions based on a query I have below:

```
SELECT
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.LeagueID ORDER BY a.LeagueID) AS WeekNumber,
    a.TeamID AS HomeTeamID,
    a.TeamAbbreviation AS HomeTeam,
    b.TeamID AS AwayTeamID,
    b.TeamAbbreviation AS AwayTeam,
    a.LeagueID AS HomeLeague,
    b.LeagueID AS AwayLeague
FROM 
    dbo.Team a
CROSS JOIN 
    dbo.Team b
WHERE 
    a.TeamID != b.TeamID
    AND b.TeamAbbreviation = 'CHE' OR a.TeamAbbreviation = 'CHE'
    AND a.LeagueID = b.LeagueID
```

Currently the query displays these results:

[image]

This is incorrect and I need help refactoring the results. What I am trying to achieve is:

1. For each match a team plays (in this example ‘CHE’), the WeekNumber column needs to update to include the correct round of fixtures. There a multiple teams so when all the teams play 1 week, it should display WeekNumber ‘1’, then the next round of matches should display WeekNumber ‘2’ and etc.
2. It displays ‘CHE’ playing against all teams when really they should only be playing against teams in the same league (hence a.LeagueID = b.LeagueID). In the screenshot it shows the team playing against other teams from other leagues (other leagueIDs).

What do I need to change to get this working?

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
WeekNumber HomeTeamID HomeTeam AwayTeamID AwayTeam HomeLeague Away League
1          4           ARS      19        CHE       1         1
2          14          BRC      19        CHE       1         1
3          15          BRR      19        CHE       1         1
```

Comment: can you show your desired output?

Comment: @Aldrin Included desired output like you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to use `JOIN` rather than `CROSS JOIN`.  But your problem are parentheses around the conditions.

Try this:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM dbo.Team a JOIN
     dbo.Team b
     ON a.LeagueID = b.LeagueID AND a.TeamID <> b.TeamID
WHERE b.TeamAbbreviation = 'CHE' OR a.TeamAbbreviation = 'CHE';
```

You can express the last condition as:

```
WHERE 'CHE' IN (a.TeamAbbreviation, b.TeamAbbreviation);
```

Comment: Cool, only issue is the rank now where want each round of matches to display the correct number (see desired output) in question

Comment: @carlBrooks . . . You might want to ask another question.  The `rank()` statement looks awkward.  It is always going to return "1".